# Any difference between these three member functions?

Tags: c++

```
class a
{
    virtual void f1()=0;
    virtual void f2();
    virtual void f3(){};
};
```

I have no idea about the difference between these three functions(newbie on C++)... Could anyone please explain it for me?

Comment: One has an extra semicolon.

Comment: virtual void f1()=0; //Pure Virtual function need to be override to use

Comment: @chris Is f2() the same with f3()?

Comment: `f2` is not defined yet, it needs to be defined somewhere outside the class. `f3` is defined, and it is defined to do nothing.